# python tests using nosgae running very slow since 1.6.3

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, nosetests

As asked in this google group post:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!topic/google-appengine-python/fQUnsnt-wJ4

I'm not sure whether yaml parsing is the root cause, but I am sure my test suite now takes several times longer to run. Anyone else run into this? Any known workarounds?

To double check I reverted to sdk verson 1.6.2 and, for example, one test suite runs 4x faster (~10s vs 40s).

Comment: I haven't noticed any changes in testing times.  I'm on a mac with Lion.  What is your OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7169.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, couldn't find an existing bug for this issue